# Where can I find the icon set Github uses?

Tags: vector, icons, github

I'm talking about the icon set that Github uses for their own site design.

[Example Page](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/)

On this page, near the top right corner, the "Watch" and "Fork" buttons, as well as the buttons next to them have *beautiful* icons!

Any idea where the full set can be found?

To clarify, I'm just looking for minimalist grey icons of that size and style to be used in web apps.

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure if the icons Github utilizes are under creative commons. However, the icon packages below are used in other popular software packages that might be a fit for your project (e.g. you can always convert to grayscale and resize them using Gimp):

[famfamfam icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/)

[fugue icons](http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/)

[mini icons 2 (already grey for you)](http://www.brandspankingnew.net/archive/2006/12/hohoho.html)

Answer (score 1):

They use wireframe mono icons. You can find them here.
http://www.iconfinder.com/search/4/?q=iconset:cc_mono_icon_set

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I think you can find them here... https://github.com/styleguide/css/7.0

Answer (score 0):

The directories seem from famfamfam... But the other answer already told you that.